# Did TexStudio make a mistake?

Tags: errors, citing, texstudio, compilation-error, newtheorem

I use the usepackage

```
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
```

Then I write normally

```
\begin{proposition} [Put name of proposition here]
...
\end{proposition}
```

If the name of your proposition is for example "Euler [1750] and Fermat", then TexStudio  will close the name after the first ] bracket and not the last one!! Something strange will be the output.
I saw that mistake, when I tried to cite like this: "\cite[][p. 99]{Serrebook}"
TexStudio showed a mistake because after "\cite[]" was a cut...

Am I wrong or is that really a mistake of Texstudio?

Comment: `\begin{proposition} [{Euler [1750] and Fermat}]` instead of `\begin{proposition} [Euler [1750] and Fermat]` should result in the expected output. (Notice the extra set of `{}` around the proposition's name here.

Comment: You are a genius!

Comment: note that texstudio is just the editor you used to write the file, it is latex that is parsing the `[..]` arguments, and that will behave the same way whichever editor you use, so texstudio is not related to the problem here.